# Setting boundary thickness and color theme in ggplot using geom_sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, spatial

I have created this county-level map of cumulative incidence of a disease (link below) using the below code, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to (1) reduce the thickness of the county boundary lines and (2) use a color theme that more clearly shows high incidence counties - I think it would help if it used a few colors instead of only dark to light blue. I know this should be simple, but I'm not very good with R - if there is a very straightforward way to update the below code I'd be grateful!

plot_variable <- ggplot(moran_scatter) +
geom_sf(aes(fill=cumincidence_cases), color="gray75")+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="bottom")

[Cumulative incidence by county](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saU5r.png)

Comment: For the boundaries, inside `geom_sf` add `size=0.5` (or whatever size value works well). For the fill colors, try adding something like `scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="blue")` or `scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", mid="white", high="blue", midpoint=2000)`. And of course you can play around with the colors to get a palette that you like.

Comment: @eipi10 - thank you so much! The fill color gradients works great, but I get this error (Error in point_size * .pt : non-numeric argument to binary operator) when I add the size: plot_variable <- ggplot(moran_scatter) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=cumincidence_cases), color="gray75", size="0.5") + scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red")+theme(legend.position="bottom"). Have tried putting the 0.5 in quotes and without, not sure where the error is coming from.

Comment: You're welcome! Regarding the error: `"0.5"` is a character string rather than a number (note the error message `non-numeric argument`). Remove the quotation marks. It should be: `0.5`.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that you said you tried it without quotes. Please post the error message you get when you use `size=0.5`.